# Certain Calendars do not trigger iPhone Notifications

Tags: ios, calendar, notifications

I've got three calendars set up on my iPhone:

- Microsoft Exchange
- outlook.com (Windows Live)
- icloud

I've got entries in the first two calendars. However, I only get notifications from the Exchange Events as set up into them (like 15 minutes before, and so on). On the other hands, I won't get notifications on outlook.com-Events.

Both calendars are synchronized exactly the same, notifications for calendar at all are set, I can see all the events with different colours in my Calendar App, but I won't get any notice at the outlook.com Events...

Anyone knows what I forgot?

Answer (score 1):

In your Calendars app, press the "Calendars" button on the bottom, and press the `(i)` that shows up next to each calendar in the list of calendars. Scroll to the bottom of the settings there, and there should be a toggle for Event Alerts. Turn this on for each individual calendar.

Comment: They are all turned on already...
Additionally, if I disable them and leave the menu, they get resetted to "enabled"....

Comment: @FlorianMüller Maybe you're not setting event alerts when you create an alert for your outlook-live calendar?

Comment: @FlorianMüller If you choose to edit one of the outlook-live calendar events, what does it say in the "Alert" field? And what about for an event in your Exchange calendar?

Comment: I can set "Notification" on both kinds of events on predefined values such as "2 days before" "5 mins before" and so on..

Comment: @FlorianMüller If you download the Outlook app, does your outlook-live calendar function as expected?

Comment: @FlorianMüller Also try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2787708